# sql query from 2 tables and php

Tags: php, sql

I have a simple php code that fetches data from a sql table.

TABLE 1

```
date_time 
name
```

and another table which store name(same as TABLE1) and picture link.

TABLE 2

```
name
pic
```

PHP

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", "$username", "$password");
$sql = "select * from table1";
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
echo '<span class=name>'.$row['name'].'</span>';
echo "<img src=".$row['pic']." width='25px' height='25px'/>";
$db = null;
}
```

What i want is to be show the picture of the name from TABLE 2(`$row['pic']`) according to name in TABLE 1.
How the sql statement and the php code should be in order to achieve this?
I run a sql statement in phpMyadmin and got it,but couldnt translate it in php code.

```
select table1.name,table2.pic from table1,table2 where table1.name=table2.name;
```

Comment: So this query is not working?

Comment: your `query` should work,once check the single and double quotes balance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.pic 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
  ON table1.name = table2.name
```

Comment: this did the work.I just didnt know how to work with INNER JOIN. I'll accept it when i can. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

try this, use `as` keyword to alias your column names, so that you can get `'name'` and `'pic'` index in the loop.

```
select 
   table1.name as `name`,
   table2.pic as `pic` 
from table1, table2 
where table1.name = table2.name;
```

a better way to do it use joins

```
select 
   `table1`.`name` as `name`,
   `table2`.`pic` as `pic` 
from `table1`
     inner join `table2`
     on `table1`.`name` = `table2`.`name`;
```